# Filling a "power grid" using a breadth-first fill algorithm; I'm stuck

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

EDIT:  I think I may have to implement a BFS in the run() function?

EDIT2:  I have updated the code to what I have now.  I'm not comfortable with it, but it seems to be adding asterisks to the power conductors successfully.  I have to output the total houses and how many are without power, but I don't know how to keep track of that amount properly.

EDIT3:  Ok, I am completely convinced that I have the filling of the grid correct.  However, I cannot manage to keep track of the amount of houses that aren't powered.  Any advice on that would be great.

Here's the idea:

I'm given an h x w matrix full of symbols.  One of them will be the letter "P" which will represent a power plant.  From that power plant, any capital letter is conductive and can carry the electricity across the map.  On top of that, there are 3 symbols that represent wires to also carry electricity.  They are: +, -, and |

Finally, there are homes represented by the letter "H".  These are conductive as well if next to any of the other conductive symbols.  The idea is to fill the grid with an asterisk "*" if power can reach it.  The catch is that each power plant P can only power 30 homes H.  The code I'm posting is obviously unfinished, but the breadth-first-fill algorithm (bff) is finished.  I can successfully fill any immediate symbol next to the P, but I am having trouble figuring out how to continue to trace away from the P with different symbols.  Any ideas are welcome.

Example input:

```
15 22
, , , , , , , , , , . . . , , , , , , , , ,
, , . , , , , , , H H H - - + , , , , , , ,
, , , , , , , , , H H H . . | . , , , . , ,
, , , , , , , , , H H H = , | . , , , . . .
, , , , , , , , , H H H = , | . , , , . . .
, , , . . . . . , H H H = , | , , , , . . .
. . . . . . . . , H H H = , | , , , , . . .
, , . , , = = = = = = = = , | , , , . . . .
, , X X X X , . . . . C C C C C C . . . . .
. . X P X X , . . . . C C C C C C . . . . .
. . X X X X - - - - - C C C C C C . . . . .
. ~ X X X X . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
~ ~ ~ ~ . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ~
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ . . . . . . . . . . . ~ ~ . ~ ~
```

Example output:

```
0 of 18 homes are without power .
, , , , , , , , , , . . . , , , , , , , , ,
, , . , , , , , , * * * * * * , , , , , , ,
, , , , , , , , , * * * . . * . , , , . , ,
, , , , , , , , , * * * = , * . , , , . . .
, , , , , , , , , * * * = , * . , , , . . .
, , , . . . . . , * * * = , * , , , , . . .
. . . . . . . . , * * * = , * , , , , . . .
, , . , , = = = = = = = = , * , , , . . . .
, , * * * * , . . . . * * * * * * . . . . .
. . * * * * , . . . . * * * * * * . . . . .
. . * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * . . . . .
. ~ * * * * . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
~ ~ ~ ~ . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ~
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ . . . . . . . . . . . ~ ~ . ~ ~
```

Code so far:

```
public class PowerGrid {
    String[][] grid = new String[120][120];
    LinkedList<Pair> q = new LinkedList<Pair>();
    LinkedList<Pair> visited = new LinkedList<Pair>();
    Map<Pair, Integer> dist = new HashMap<Pair, Integer>();
    ArrayList<Pair> pwrPlants = new ArrayList<Pair>();
    String[] alphabet = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L",
            "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};  
    int row = -1;
    int col = -1;

    int homesToPwr = 0;
    int homesNotPwrd = 0;
    int totalHomes = 0;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        PowerGrid pg = new PowerGrid();
        pg. run();

    }

    public void run() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        row = sc.nextInt();
        col = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = sc.next();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                if (grid[i][j].equals("P")) {
                    Pair tmpPair = new Pair(i, j);
                    pwrPlants.add(tmpPair);
                }
            }

        for (Pair p : pwrPlants) {
            homesToPwr += 30;
            for (String s : alphabet) {
                if (s == "H") 
                    if (homesToPwr != 0) 
                        homesToPwr--;                       

                bff(grid, p.x, p.y, s, "*");
            }

            bff(grid, p.x, p.y, "-", "*");
            bff(grid, p.x, p.y, "+", "*");
            bff(grid, p.x, p.y, "|", "*");
        }

        System.out.println(homesToPwr + " of " + totalHomes + " are without power.");

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void bff (String[][] grid, int x, int y, String oldSymbol, String newSymbol) {
        if (oldSymbol == newSymbol) return;


        Pair pair = new Pair(x,y);
        q.addLast(pair);
        dist.put(pair, 0);
        grid[x][y] = newSymbol;

        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            Pair v = q.getFirst();
            q.pop();
            int d = dist.get(v) + 1;
            String[] symbols = {"+", "-", "|"};

            visit(grid, v.x + 1, v.y, new Pair(v.x+1, v.y), oldSymbol, newSymbol, d);
            visit(grid, v.x - 1, v.y, new Pair(v.x-1, v.y), oldSymbol, newSymbol, d);
            visit(grid, v.x, v.y + 1, new Pair(v.x, v.y+1), oldSymbol, newSymbol, d);
            visit(grid, v.x, v.y - 1, new Pair(v.x, v.y-1), oldSymbol, newSymbol, d);

            for (String t : alphabet){
                if (t == "H") {
                    if (homesToPwr != 0) {
                        homesToPwr--;
                    }
                }

                    visit(grid, v.x + 1, v.y, new Pair(v.x+1, v.y), t, newSymbol, d);
                    visit(grid, v.x - 1, v.y, new Pair(v.x-1, v.y), t, newSymbol, d);
                    visit(grid, v.x, v.y + 1, new Pair(v.x, v.y+1), t, newSymbol, d);
                    visit(grid, v.x, v.y - 1, new Pair(v.x, v.y-1), t, newSymbol, d);

            }
            for (String s : symbols) {
                visit(grid, v.x + 1, v.y, new Pair(v.x+1, v.y), s, newSymbol, d);
                visit(grid, v.x - 1, v.y, new Pair(v.x-1, v.y), s, newSymbol, d);
                visit(grid, v.x, v.y + 1, new Pair(v.x, v.y+1), s, newSymbol, d);
                visit(grid, v.x, v.y - 1, new Pair(v.x, v.y-1), s, newSymbol, d);
            }
        }
    }

    public void visit (String[][] A, int x, int y, Pair pair, String oldSymbol, String newSymbol, int d) {
        if ((x >= 0 && y >= 0) && (x < row && y < col) && A[x][y].equals(oldSymbol)) {
            if (oldSymbol == "H")
                totalHomes++;
            A[x][y] = newSymbol;
            dist.put(pair, d);
            q.addLast(pair);

        }
    }

    public class Pair {
        int x, y;
        public Pair (int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public String toString() {
            String out = "X: " + this.x + "  Y: " + this.y;
            return out;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @CoryKendall Haha, why is that?

Comment: I think you are missing the other power conducting characters like +, -, and |

Comment: I have updated the code showing how I think I fixed the filling of the grid.  However, I cannot seem to properly keep track of how many houses are without power.

Comment: So you need a flood fill algorithm. Your question is a bit too broad for SO IMHO, but you could get started by reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure that's what the breadth-first fill that I included in the code is for.

Comment: I don't understand your problem.  You have 18 homes.  All of them get power.  You are then printing out that 0 out of 18 are without power.  It looks correct to me.

Comment: Use recursion. Your code doesn't need to be as long as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is not counting the total nomber of houses correctly.

For instance there are 19 houses here but only 18 are counted by the visit method. This is because you only visit cases that are "connected" to the powerplant.

```
15 22
, , , , , , , , , , . . . , , , , , , , , ,
, , . , , , , H , H H H - - + , , , , , , ,
, , , , , , , , , H H H . . | . , , , . , ,
, , , , , , , , , H H H = , | . , , , . . .
, , , , , , , , , H H H = , | . , , , . . .
, , , . . . . . , H H H = , | , , , , . . .
. . . . . . . . , H H H = , | , , , , . . .
, , . , , = = = = = = = = , | , , , . . . .
, , X X X X , . . . . C C C C C C . . . . .
. . X P X X , . . . . C C C C C C . . . . .
. . X X X X - - - - - C C C C C C . . . . .
. ~ X X X X . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
~ ~ ~ ~ . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ~
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ . . . . . . . . . . . ~ ~ . ~ ~
```

You can count the total amount of houses this way :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = sc.next();
            if(grid[i][j].equals("H")){
                totalHomes++;
            }
        }
```

Then count the actual number of powered houses this way (I used a new attribute homesPwrd (=0), only modified by this method, not sure what all your other integers are good for ...) :

```
public void visit (String[][] A, int x, int y, Pair pair, String oldSymbol, String newSymbol, int d) {
    if ((x >= 0 && y >= 0) && (x < row && y < col) && A[x][y].equals(oldSymbol)) {
        if (oldSymbol == "H")
            homesPwrd++;
        A[x][y] = newSymbol;
        dist.put(pair, d);
        q.addLast(pair);

    }
}
```

Finally

```
    System.out.println(totalHomes-homesPwrd + " of " + totalHomes + " are without power.");
```

Output

1 of 19 are without power.

```
    1 of 19 are without power.
    ,,,,,,,,,,...,,,,,,,,,
    ,,.,,,,H,******,,,,,,,
    ,,,,,,,,,***..*.,,,.,,
    ,,,,,,,,,***=,*.,,,...
    ,,,,,,,,,***=,*.,,,...
    ,,,.....,***=,*,,,,...
    ........,***=,*,,,,...
    ,,.,,========,*,,,....
    ,,****,....******.....
    ..****,....******.....
    ..***************.....
    .~****................
    ~~~~..................
    ~~~~~................~
    ~~~~~~...........~~.~~
```